# Android Views Palette Missing for Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Ok i created a new project in Eclipse for Android. My MainActivity is what was given to me. It has an activity_main.xml in the res.layout folder that i can drag and drop widgets onto the activity.

I created a new Activity called SurveyActivity but I can not find the xml file that allows me to use the palette.

Did i do something wrong when creating the activity or is there more that i need to do to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume you created a class(and not an Activity, which can be done with ADT 20) and extended Activity. Then you have to create a layout xml by your own. Right click on te layout folder -> new -> Android xml file. Set this layout in your `setContentView()` of your Activity. 
And don't forget to register that Activity in your Manifest.